# How to align output numbers (or text) to the right in c?

Tags: c, alignment, printf

I have a task to get a positive integer from the user, and then print a triangle that will look like this (for the integer 5 for example):

```
          1
        1 2
      1 3 5
   1 4 7 10
1 5 9 13 17
```

this is the code that I managed to make:

```
int num, line,addition,sum,termNum;
printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

printf("%d\n",1);

for (line=2;line<=num;line++)
{
   addition = line-1;
   termNum=1;
   printf("%d ",termNum);

   for (sum=2;sum<=line;sum++)
   {
       termNum+=addition;
       printf("%d ",termNum);
   }
   printf("\n");

}
```

But the output is not aligned to the right, it looks like this:

```
1
1 2
1 3 5
1 4 7 10
1 5 9 13 17
```

I cant create functions or use arrays, only loops and ifs, and the various control characters such as %c %s %d %-12c etc...
Variable types must be int,double,char. (not strings or char* etc)

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: We are no homwork service. If there was only a way to print spaces  ...

Comment: @Olaf I come here after i've tried for about 2 hours... I can print spaces like this: char s = ' ' ;    printf("%c",s); but how can i tell exactly how many i'll need for each line?

Comment: If there was a way to repeat one or multiple statements ... In programing, one should think before asking ...

Answer (score 0):

OP a needs nudge to pre-calculate maximum line width.

Below fill-in-the-blank code calculates the max line width, which seem to be OP's stumbling block.

```
int main(void) {
  int x = 5;
  int width = 0;
  for (int col = 0; col < ___ ; col++) { // How many iterations?
    int value = col* ___ + ___;          // Determine each value: 1 5 9 13 17      
    // find print width
    do {
      width++;  // add 1 per digit       
      value /= ___;                      // What base is the number displayed?
    } while (value > ___);               // When to quit (hint:  not much)
    width++;  // add 1 for ' ' separator 
  }
  printf("%d\n", width);                 // Should be a dozen
}
```

Alternative

```
  for (int col = 0; col < ___ ; col++) {
    int value = col* ___ + ___;
    width += snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d ", value);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Maximum printed number will be the very last number. That is line
`num` and column `num`. It will thus be `1 + (num - 1) ^ 2`.

The printed width of a decimal number `N` is `ceil(log(N+1) / log(10))`.

The easiest way to align your numbers is to print them all the same
width, that is the width of the maximum number:
`ceil(log(1 + (num - 1) ^ 2) / log(10))`.

```
int num, line, addition, sum, termNum;
printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
scanf("%d", &num);
int width = ceil(log10(1 + 1 + (num - 1) * (num - 1)));
char format[] = "%0000000000d%c";
sprintf(format, "%%%dd%%c", width);
for (sum = 1 + 1; sum <= num; sum++) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= width; i++)
        putchar(' ');
}
printf(format, 1, '\n');
for (line = 2; line <= num; line++) {
    for (sum = line + 1; sum <= num; sum++) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= width; i++)
            putchar(' ');
    }
    addition = line - 1;
    termNum = 1;
    printf(format, termNum, ' ');
    for (sum = 2;sum <= line; sum++) {
        termNum += addition;
        printf(format, termNum, ' ');
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks but we cant use ceil() or sprintf, and format[] is an array(right?) so we cant use that either...

Comment: That is way too complicated. And we don't do homework coding!

Comment: @Olaf dont do my homework for me, give a hint in the right direction if you know how (?)...or is that too against the rules?

Comment: @user7387595 `ceill()` is just one way to find the length of printed representation of a number. You can also find it by counting the number of times you need to divide by 10.

Comment: @user7387595 similarly, `sprintf()` and `format[]` are used to take advantage of C's alignement capabilities. But you could do the padding with successive calls to `printf(" ")`. Or if you know what the maximum number your exercise has to work with, you can simplify for that value.

Comment: @user7387595 A problem with "we cant use ceil() or sprintf," is that it is a restriction, buried in a comment not in the post where it belongs, well after the the post.  This implies any answer with be followed with a "Thanks but we cant use ... this or that".  Best to clearly state goals and all restrictions up front - in the post.

Comment: "we can't use sprintf, arrays or functions"? I want to have a good talk with whoever set you this homework!

Comment: in the end we were allowed to answer this problem "up to a certain degree" which means it needs to work up to base 12 or so, that way it is possible to do it just using 1-3 loops without anything special